# Magento place order / checkout time out - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I'm getting 502 erros when I try to place an order in Magento, I also tried to disable Downloadable products and RSS feeds.

I receive the orde confirmation email, the stock is update and at the admin panel I can see the order correctly but I don't get the success message at checkout/onepage/success/ instead I get an 502 error caused by a timeout.

The only error message that I'm getting is os nginx log:

```
2013/12/21 18:49:47 [error] 18449#0: *191 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 177.103.69.141, server: dev.canalagricola.com.br, request: "GET /checkout/onepage/success/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "dev.canalagricola.com.br", referrer: "http://dev.canalagricola.com.br/checkout/onepage/"
```

I'm using Amazon Linux (64 bits) on a small instance (PHP5.5, PHPFPM-5.5, Nginx 1.4.3, Mysql 5.5, Magento 1.8.1)

magento.conf (nginx)

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     dev.canalagricola.com.br;

    access_log      off;

    root            /var/www/canalagricola;
    index           index.php;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss;
    gzip_disable    "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;
    tcp_nopush      on;

    keepalive_timeout       30;
    keepalive_requests      100000;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    client_body_timeout     10;
    send_timeout            2;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
            expires 30d;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
            log_not_found     off;
            expires           1y;
    }

    location ^~ /(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }

    location /var/export/ { internal; }

    location /. { return 404; }

    location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }

    location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }

    location ~* .php$ {
            if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
            expires off;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE    default;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE    store;
            fastcgi_read_timeout            300;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

    location /lib/minify/ {
            allow all;
    }
}
```

www.conf (php-fpm)

```
[www]

listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0664
user = nginx
group = nginx

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 4
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_requests = 200
request_terminate_timeout = 300s
rlimit_files = 131072
rlimit_core = unlimited
catch_workers_output = yes

php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 1024M
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 300000

php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/5.5/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/5.5/session
```

Answer (score 0):

apc needs to be disabled few hours, then you can plug it in. and read logs again.
there is eaccelerator as well, works sometimes even better.

disable full page cache and apc and run
ab -c 1 -n 1 http://www.campsaver.com/

then restart with apc

see speed, read logs and enable full page cache if good.

Comment: Dear Arshad, I didn´t install APC yet on this server

Answer (score 0):

```
Okay,

The above nginx error indicate that issue is related to the fastcgi(php-fpm).

After enabling the "catch_workers_output" on /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf Got the relevant error on php5-fpm.log. Now understand that issue is related to AMQP module.

[21-Aug-2013 23:32:57] WARNING: [pool www] child 16091 said into stderr: "php-fpm: pool www: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/php5/20090626/amqp.so: undefined symbol: amqp_open_socket"

Issue has been fixed afterrecompiled and install amqp module
```

Comment: Dear Arshad, I had enabled catch_workers_output and I get the log message that I showed on the post. There is no relationship with amqp module, it isn't installed on this server.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are using PHP 5.5

According to the requirements the recommended PHP version to use is 5.2.13 - 5.3.24
http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements

Install the recommended PHP version to see if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your PHP-FPM:

```
/etc/init.d/php55-php-fpm restart
```

If this issue persists, you can increase buffer and timeouts inside HTTP block:

```
http {
    ...
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    ...
}
```